Can't get Datastore composite index to work from App Engine Go
I have a Google App Engine Go app that uses Datastore. I am attempting to implement a query that involves inequalities for two properties. I cannot get the composite index to work.
Here is the schema for the kind:
type LicenseKeyUsage struct {
    First      time.Time
    Last       time.Time
    Count      int
    Days       int
}

Here is a snippet from the query (lastMin is set to a time and d is set to an integer):
aggregationCountQuery := datastore.NewQuery("LicenseKeyUsage").
    FilterField("Last", ">=", lastMin).
    FilterField("Days", ">=", d).
    NewAggregationQuery().
    WithCount("active_count")

Here is my index.yaml located in the same directory as app.yaml:
indexes:

- kind: LicenseKeyUsage
  properties:
  - name: Last
  - name: Days

I deploy the index file using the command gcloud app deploy index.yaml, then I go to the datastore console to wait until the index is ready, then I update an entity that should get indexed.
From the console, the index is showing no entities.
If I attempt to run my query, I get the following error:
rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = The query contains range and inequality filters on multiple fields, please refer to the documentation for index selection best practices: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/multiple-range-fields. One possible index to serve the query is:
- kind: LicenseKeyUsage
  properties:
  - name: Days
  - name: Last

First of all, the order of the properties in the recommended index do not match the order of my field filters in the query. I switched to that index, but I still get the same error.
Any idea what is going wrong here?

Can you try updating your gcloud CLI to the latest version and redeploy. Also make sure to use the latest version of gcloud CLI. Can you try deploying with --verbosity=debug flag and share the output. Also have a look at this Document1 and Document2.

@SandeepVokkareni I just tried that, but I get the same results. The gcloud command succeeds, so there is no error response from the command. The datastore index console shows that the index was created. It just doesn't seem to be picking up any entity data. Once I start adding entities, the "entries" column in the datastore index console should show the number of entities, correct? It just shows "-".

@SandeepVokkareni I think I discovered the issue. I am not using the default database. When I create an index, it is getting created in the default database. I cannot find in the documentation how to create a index in a database other than the default database. Do you know how that is done or where it is documented?

I discovered the cause of this problem. The index was getting created for the default database, but the queries were targeting a non-default database.
